# Show the SaveAs Dialog Box when Save button is clicked using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, save-as

I want to save my data on my local drive but I first want to open the saveAs dialog box. How can I do that? Im using AngularJS

This is the code that I have

```
    <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="dialogs.saveAs()">
<div id="dvData">
<script type="text/javascript">
```

The whole code is on this plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/eWBi9uPVX5tJWwTsCVOd?p=preview

Comment: This question has already been answered a handful of times, most notably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Comment: @RexM sorry I saw that already but I can't seem to understand it. I'm new in angular

Comment: angular is just Javascript, nothing special. Take any of the solutions, put them in a Javascript function, and call the function from ng-click.

Comment: @RexM I still cant get it. If its not too much can you give me a sample demo?

Comment: I have forked your plunker and modified it. see http://plnkr.co/edit/GDoPUhvbQCe0vUuUDXhR?p=preview

Comment: thanks @sdfacre but as I click the button the dialog box that shows is for open file and for save as . How can I make the dialog box opening is for save as?

Comment: do I need to use factory, directives and other stuffs?

Comment: bleyk, I am also getting the open dialogbox instead of saveas, please share the code if you have for save as. Thank you

Comment: @sdfacre, could you please help me